# Sugerencias en estructura de bala

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Mi software tiene un número variable de usuarios en la siguiente tabla:

```
  USER_ID        int IDENTITY(1, 1),
  USER_NAME      varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  USER_PASSWORD  varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  USER_STATUS    int,
  PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID)
)
```

Y tiene un número variable de cuentas bancarias de acuerdo a la siguiente tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ACCOUNTS (
  ID_ACCOUNT      int IDENTITY(1, 1),
  NAME          varchar(50),
  BALANCE        float DEFAULT 0,
  STATUS         char DEFAULT 'A',
  /* Keys */
  PRIMARY KEY (ID_ACCOUNT)
)
GO
```

---

Quiero crear una tabla de permisos donde a cada usuario se le asigne la(s) cuentas bancarias a las que tendrá acceso.

¿Cual sería la estructura adecuada para la tabla de permisos?

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español, te pido que cambies el idioma de tu publicación, ya que esta comunidad es en el español

Comment: Que gestor usas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente se crea una tabla que tenga las llaves de ambas tablas creando una llave primaria para la combinación de las mismas y llaves foráneas para relacionarlas con las tablas de usuarios y cuentas.

```
CREATE TABLE USERS_ACCOUNTS(
    USER_ID int,
    ID_ACCOUNT int
    PRIMARY KEY( USER_ID, ID_ACCOUNT)
)

ALTER TABLE USERS_ACCOUNTS ADD CONSTRAINT FK_USERS_ACCOUNTS_USERS FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID) REFERENCES dbo.USERS;
ALTER TABLE USERS_ACCOUNTS ADD CONSTRAINT FK_USERS_ACCOUNTS_ACCOUNTS FOREIGN KEY (ID_ACCOUNT) REFERENCES dbo.ACCOUNTS;
```

Comment: ¿recomiendas utilizar las foreign keys desde la base de datos? o ¿mejor directo en el lenguaje de programación hago la validación que exista la clave en la otra tabla? ¿cual de estas 2 es la mejor práctica?

Comment: La mejor práctica siempre es mantener la integridad referencial en la base de datos. De esa forma, no se necesita programar en todos los sistemas que interactuen con ella. La única excepción a esta regla es en data warehouses.